# Calculating Magnetic Vector&Scalar Potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want to calculate the magnetic scalar and vector potentials for an infinite axial current density given as
\begin{equation}
J(r,\varphi) =  \frac{I}{R} \delta(r-R) \sin\varphi \cos\varphi \bf{\hat{k}}.
\end{equation}
For the vector potential, I think I need to go with the following integral
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{x}) =  \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\mathbf{J(x')}}{\bf|x-x'|}d^3x'
\end{equation}
I think I need some simplifications at this point but couldn't come up with anything.

As for magnetic scalar potential, I am confused. It says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_scalar_potential) it is only defined in regions where there is no current. Then how to calculate it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *I think I need some simplifications.* The delta function simplifies the integral over $r’$.

Comment: *magnetic scalar potential … is only defined in regions where there is no current* Which is almost everywhere.